# Polymer - get a divs position that sits in the shadow dom

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

I am currently building a custom element with Polymer. Now I want to get a div that sits in my custom element to perform a certain function onclick and in that function I need to get it's position relative to the view port.

So normally I'd use

```
var offsets = element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Now in the custom element - assuming the div that I am talking about has the ID innerCard so it would be

```
this.$.innerCard.onclick = function(){
alert("Test 1");
var offsets = this.$.innerCard.shadowRoot.getBoundingClientRect();
alert("Test 2");
....
}
```

The first alert triggers correctly, but the second one doesn't. The Javascript Console gives me a type error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerCard' of undefined tile-story.html:37$.innerCard.onclick tile-story.html:37
```

Does anyone know how I can access the divs position otherwise or what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Could innerCard provide a public function to return its offset?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. I simply have declared a div like so: <div id="innerCard" class="card">Content_here</div>

Comment: How about bind your handler's `this` first?

Comment: @cameron I am sorry this may sound dumb but could you provide an example? Right now the full code looks like this:
http://nopaste.info/0879d9128f.html
edit: there is a ";" missing but even with that it won't work obviously.

Comment: Explained in answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The undefined error is because in onclick handler, `this` is not same as the outer `this`, so if you want to use `this.$`, you should bind the context first:

```
 Polymer('tile-story', {
        ready: function() {
            this.$.innerCard.onclick = function() {
                var offsets = this.$.innerCard.getBoundingClientRect(); //ClientRect {height: 18, width: 1350, left: 8, bottom: 44, right: 1358…}
            }.bind(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For me this is the most convenient way of doing it I think.

Comment: Instead of using `.onclick`, you should attach the listener in your template. E.g. `<div id="innerCard" on-tap="{{cardTap}}">...</div>`, then you can declare a method in your element called `cardTap` to do the work: `cardTap: function() { var offsets = this.$.innerCard.getBoundingClientRect() ... },`. I suggest `tap` instead of `click` because it will work for touchevents, but you could replace `tap` with `click` in my example and it will work also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Polymer's declarative event binding to make your life easier. E.g.:

```
<polymer-element name="x-foo">
  <template>
    <p on-tap="{{measureMe}}">Some Content</p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      measureMe: function(e) {
        var rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
        alert(JSON.stringify(rect));
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

This way, the code and the view know less about each other, which will make your projects easier to maintain. There are no concerns around `this`, and no need to query for specific nodes.

You can use `on-click` instead of `on-tap` if you wish. The `tap` gesture event is generated by Polymer and works with touch events or mouse events.

http://jsbin.com/puqas/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

To get info about the component you can provide public methods on the component itself. As per your use case, this returns the clientRect of a div inside the component:

```
<x-card></x-card>

<polymer-element name="x-card">
    <template>
        <div id="innerCard" class="card">Content_here</div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('x-card', {
            getBoundingClientRect: function () {
                return this.$.innerCard.getBoundingClientRect();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
        var card = document.querySelector('x-card');
        var rect = card.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(rect); // {height: 18, width: 336, left: 8, bottom: 26, right: 344…} 
    });
</script>
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/imcg/68cf0zvy/)

Comment: Thank you for the example. I got it to work but I think I'll end up using the one below because it is easier for me to work with.

Comment: Fwiw, this answer is wrong and the example is actually broken. The `#innerCard` div is not inside a `<template>` so it's ignored by Polymer and shows up directly in the document by itself. The custom element has no nodes. In general `document.querySelector` does not penetrate shadow-dom (unless you use special selectors), so if the element were set up correctly, the given query would actually fail.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that Scott, I've updated the answer to remove any future confusion

Comment: Yep, that's all good now. Thank you for this answer because I focused on the event handling bit which I suspect is only tangential to the OPs actual problem. Your answer is likely more on point.